# women's vs woman's

Tags: grammar, possessives

Are the following sentences correct?

1. These are women’s accessories.  They are not men’s.
2. These are lady’s high heels.  They are obviously not men’s.
3. This isn’t a woman’s vest.  It’s a man’s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes all your sentences are correct, but you missed something important with the apostrophe. Correct answer:

> These are women's accessories. They are not men’s.

> These are ladies' high heels. They are obviously not men’s.

> This isn’t a woman’s vest. It’s a man’s.

The first sentence is an exception. Because 'women' is already plural, and is possessive, you can just add a "**'s**". It would only be "womens'" if "womens" without the apostrophe was the plural of woman.

Comment: So is all of the following correct then?
"*This is children’s clothing. It is not adult’s. It’s not adult clothing."
"It’s a child’s tracksuit."
"It’s not a lady’s tracksuit.*"

Comment: Oh how about this.  The coat's collar's stained.  The "coat's" is POSSESSION while "collar's" is contraction.  Is that quite normal?  Or is better to use longer form "The coat's collar is"?

Comment: Yes you have to use the longer form @GreenKhan

Comment: _It's not adults'_ because _adult_ is not plural.

Comment: I thought adults = adults' and adult = adult's.

Comment: @DialFrost I don't agree. "The coat's collar's stained" looks fine to me. It doesn't get 100% on readability and it would be inappropriate for academic writing, but it's correct and natural enough in normal use

Comment: Ah ok thanks @gotube, I thought it looked akward at first